# wordpress - how to get current term in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I want to get current term in functions. but apparently this function does not work in `functions.php`. Is there an idea to solve this problem?

```
$term = get_term_by('name', get_query_var('download_tag'), 'download_tag' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * getCurrentTerm 
 * get the current term which archive is being displayed
 * good for categories, tags and custom taxonomies
 * @author Ohad Raz
 * @return current term object or false is not in a term archive.
 */
function getCurrentTerm(){
    if (!is_category() && !is_tag() && !is_tax())
        return false;
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    return get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
}
```